# Proof that there exists a rational^irrational=irrational

Tags: proof-writing, irrational-numbers

How do I prove that there exist some $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a^b \in\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$? I dont need to find what it is, just that it exists. The only numbers I know are irrational for the purposes of this proof are $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt[3]{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$, and $log_{2}3$, but I could prove the irrationality of some other number if I needed it to prove this.

Comment: How about $2^\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @molarmass  how would you prove $2^{\sqrt 2}$ is irrational?

Comment: By the Gelfond–Schneider theorem, $2^\sqrt{2}$ is transcendental and thus it is irrational. In fact, this number is known as the Gelfond–Schneider constant.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: How big is the set $\left\{2^b:b\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\right\}$? How many rationals are there?

Answer (score 2):

If $a > 0$ and $a \ne 1$ then $a^x$ is injective, one to one.  As there are uncountibly meany $x$ there are uncountably many $a^x$.  As there are only countably many rationals, not all of the $a^x$ can be rational.

Answer (score 1):

Given the list of values you know to be irrational, we could simply take  $$2^{\log_2 \sqrt 3}=\sqrt 3$$

We remark that $\log_2\sqrt 3 =\frac {\log_2 3}2$ so that too must be irrational (given that $\log_2 3$ is irrational).